# Trying to write a validation loop in Xcode 7 (Swift 2) for an iOS mobile app - stuck on infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am attempting to create an app (iOS) where a random number generator is used to display an arithmetic problem. The random number generator will decide what operation the user will perform (multiplication, subtraction, addition) and which operands are used. The user can select the difficulty level by using a segmented control.

The user is offered three attempts to provide the correct answer. The user will enter their answer into a text field and then press a button to submit their answer. If the user does not answer correctly after the third attempt, the program will display the correct answer and a new problem will be shown.

I am having difficulties written the code to provide the user with three attempts. As of now, I have successfully created an infinite loop. Below is a portion of my code (note: int i is currently a global variable):

```
@IBAction func submitAnswer(sender: UIButton) {

    var newAnswer=0

    if enteredAnswer.text!.isEmpty {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Please enter an answer.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else {
        let textAnswer: String = enteredAnswer.text!
        let userAnswer = Int(textAnswer)!

        if correctAnswer != userAnswer && i < 3{
            newAnswer = userAnswer

            while newAnswer != correctAnswer {
                feedback.text = "Try Again!"
                enteredAnswer.text = ""
                newAnswer = Int(textAnswer)!
                i+=1
            }

        }

        if correctAnswer == userAnswer {
            feedback.text = "Correct Answer!"
            enteredAnswer.text = ""
            score += 1
            scoreValue.text = String(score)
            i=0
            setProblem()
        }

        else {
            feedback.text = "The correct answer \n in \n \(correctAnswer)!"
            enteredAnswer.text = ""
            score -= 1
            scoreValue.text = String(score)
            i=0
            setProblem()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break the while loop only:

```
     while newAnswer != correctAnswer {
                feedback.text = "Try Again!"
                enteredAnswer.text = ""
                newAnswer = Int(textAnswer)!
                i+=1
                if i == 3 {
                    break
                }
            }
```

if you want to make your game work:

```
if newAnswer != correctAnswer {
    feedback.text = "Try Again!"
    enteredAnswer.text = ""
    newAnswer = Int(textAnswer)!
    i+=1
    if (i<3){
        return
    }
}
```